# How to go back to previous page on duplicate primary key along with message to user

Tags: php, html, sql

I have one page that allows the user to enter variables to be placed into a table. Then there is a post processing page which will take those variables and plug them into an sql statement, and then run the query. All of the fields on the first page are validated before being able to submit and move on to the post processing page.

I am trying to find a method so that if the primary key already exists (it's a composite primary key), the user will be sent back to the first page with a message saying that the primary key already exists. As it stands if the primary key exists, I get the SQL error message on the post processing page, so the sql does not run. This is what I want, but I want the user to know that and be able to fill out the form again.

Any help is greatly appreciated, please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: `header('Location: originalpage.php?msg=Duplicate key')`? There's MANY ways to get a message back to the user. Pick one.

Comment: This would be great if I could get it to work, but I get this warning:
    Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already      sent by (output started at     /home/nbastakm/public_html/si3.php:46) in /home/nbastakm/public_html/si3.php on line 52

I already use header function to redirect to login page if not already logged in. I guess it is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Query the primary key itself. 
If the sql result < 1 . 
Proceed to the query you have now.
If there is a result, the primary key exists,
Go back to registration.